# Magento 1.9.3.2 - attribute showing in backend for only one category

Tags: category, attributes, magento-1

Today I added two new attributes, assigned to the default attribute set.

Scope: Global, Apply To: All Product Types, Visible on view: Yes, Used in Product Listing: Yes

I was happily implementing and testing and everything was working fine for the one product I was testing - attributes were showing both back end and front end and even got a view.phtml edit to display a attribute dependent static block working.

THEN I checked/edited another product, and the attributes where not visible in the back end for that product.

I then checked other products and  - only products in the original category of the one product I was testing on are showing the attributes.  No other products in any other category.

I tried moving the attributes from 'General' to 'Price' group and they move in the back end the products they were already working ok (that single category) however are still not showing on any other product.

I have cleared cache both back end and manual, re-index multiple time and no joy.

It feels like I am missing something simple but I just can not work it out.  I have checked and cant see any way that I may have mistakenly limited the attribute to a category and just can not work out what is going on.

Any thoughts or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked attribute set for product that you are testing and the other products?

Comment: Oh my god, I knew I was being stupid :) Thank you!  Its been a  while since I worked in Magento and had it in my mind that the default set applied to all products with other sets being 'secondary' or additional to the default.  I had forgotten that I needed to add them to EVERY attribute set.

It just by luck happened that the product I was testing only used the default set.

Thanks again

Comment: I have added it as answer please accept so that other may helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for not showing one attribute for all product might be the products are not belongs to the same **attribute set**. So products should be same **attribute set** as well as **attribute should be assigned to that set** to visible the attribute in all products